# YAML Saving and Retrieving

Tags: python-3.x, pyyaml

I am working on a bot for Discord. The thing is I am using ffprobe to get the Title and Artist of all songs inside a folder. Now, I want to save this information to a YAML file so that I can retrieve it later quickly when my user types !playlist. Here is my current code.

````
 # Music Player codes---------------
    if message.content.startswith('!load'.format(self.user.mention)):
        await self.send_message(message.channel, 'Hooked to the voice channel. Please wait while'
                                                 ' I populate the list of songs.')

        global player
        global voice_stream

        if self.is_voice_connected():
            await self.send_message(message.channel,
                                    '```Discord API doesnt let me join multiple servers at the moment.```')

        else:
            voice_stream = await self.join_voice_channel(message.author.voice_channel)

        # TODO get a better way to store local playlist
        try:
            ids = 0
            global s_dict
            s_list = []
            s_playlist = []
            a = glob.glob('./audio_library/*.mp3')
            for a in a:
                try:
                    b = a.replace('\\', '/')
                    ids += 1
                    s_list.append(ids)
                    s_list.append(b)
                    print(b)
                    p = sp.Popen(['ffprobe', '-v', 'quiet', '-print_format', 'json=compact=1', '-show_format',
                                  b], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
                    op = p.communicate()
                    op_json = json.loads(op[0].decode('utf-8'))
                    title = op_json['format']['tags']['title']
                    artist = op_json['format']['tags']['artist']
                    await self.send_message(message.channel,
                                            title + ' - ' + artist + ' (code: **' + str(ids) + '**)')
                    s_playlist.append(ids)
                    s_playlist.append(title + ' - ' + artist)

                except Exception as e:
                    print(str(e))
        except:
            await self.send_message(message.channel,
                                    '```No songs in the directory lol.```')

        s_playlist_dict = dict(s_playlist[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(s_playlist), 2))
        with open('./configuration/playListInfo.yaml', 'w') as f2:
            yaml.dump(s_playlist_dict, f2, default_flow_style=False)

        s_dict = dict(s_list[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(s_list), 2))
        with open('./configuration/song_list.yaml', 'w') as f1:
            yaml.dump(s_dict, f1, default_flow_style=False)
````

Ok. So this results in a file like this.

```
1: A Party Song (The Walk of Shame) - All Time Low
2: Therapy - All Time Low
3: Barefoot Blue Jean Night - Jake Owen
```

And later when I try to use !playlist, whose code is

````
 if message.content.startswith('!playlist'):

        try:
            # Loading configurations from config.yaml
            with open('./configuration/playListInfo.yaml', 'r') as f3:
                plist = yaml.load(f3)
            idq = 1
            print(plist[idq])
            plistfinal = ''
            for plist in plist:
                song = plist[idq]
                plistfinal += str(song + str(idq) + '\n')
                idq += 1

            print(plistfinal)

        except Exception as e:
            await self.send_message(message.channel,
                                    '```' + str(e) + '```')
````

I get a error **'int' object is not subscriptable**.

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-    packages\discord\client.py", line 254, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/dell/Desktop/Python Projects/lapzbot/lapzbot.py", line 198, in on_message
song = plist[idq]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

What's the best way to store this info and retrieve it later as cleanly as possible?

Comment: *I get a error* what error?

Comment: 'int' object is not subscriptable. This error. I will update it in my post as well. Ty.

Comment: updated the error message in full. Its on line 198, which is this line                 song = plist[idq]

Comment: `for plist in plist:` what are you doing here? Why use the same var name? You're asking for trouble

Comment: Ok. I tried changing it liek this:- `for plistas in plist:`. I am still getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plist` is both the name of the data structure (mapping/dict) as well as the iterator for its keys, that is not going to work because in the `for` loop `plist` will be a key. Better do something like the following:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

yaml_str = """\
1: A Party Song (The Walk of Shame) - All Time Low
2: Therapy - All Time Low
3: Barefoot Blue Jean Night - Jake Owen
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)

print(data[1])
print('---')

plistfinal = ''
for idq, plist in enumerate(data):
    song = data[plist]
    plistfinal += (str(song) + str(idq) + '\n')

print(plistfinal)
```

which prints:

```
A Party Song (The Walk of Shame) - All Time Low
---
A Party Song (The Walk of Shame) - All Time Low0
Therapy - All Time Low1
Barefoot Blue Jean Night - Jake Owen2
```

I don't see a particular problem with your use of a mapping/dict as datastructure. Although if the key for the values, is always going to be an integer with incremental values, you might as well write it out as a sequence/list.